# How many gravitons are there in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, quantum-gravity

It is usually said that there are $10^{90}$ (real) photons in the universe.

Is there such a canonical number for real gravitons as well? Or an estimate?

Comment: I don't want to start a debate over whether "virtual particles exist", but that count will be for real photons. I don't think we expect a similar large number of real gravitons.

Comment: The question is meant to be about real particles only. I clarified this. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, who says there are $10^{90}$ real photons?

Comment: @knzhou I've not seen that number before, but it's in line with (i) a wide range of proton count estimates & (ii) the photon/proton ratio, which is often discussed in "protons slightly outnumbered the antiprotons they annihilated" discussions of Sakharov conditions.

Comment: Gravitons have not yet been found, so are simply theoretical at this point.  Personally, I doubt that they exist, and that gravity is created by gluon spin in the gluon field.  Makes more sense to me.

Comment: "It is usually said..." By whom? Including a citation to some authoritative source may be helpful.

Comment: Light implies that photons exist. Gravitational waves imply that gravitons exist.

Comment: @Christian that's not the case, we don't have an experimentally validated theory of quantum gravity. Photons are not a logical necessity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, where is that number of photons coming from?
It is computed by looking at the number density of CMB photons (which are the vast majority of total photons), roughly $410$ photons per cubic centimetre, and multiplying it by the comoving volume corresponding to the observable universe.

So, the equivalent question for gravitons is to ask what is their number density.
That's a hard question since, unlike with photons, we do not have tons of direct observational evidence at every conceivable wavelength of Gravitational Waves.

Specifically, what we currently have are several upper bounds: if GWs with a certain wavelength had more than a certain amplitude, we would have detected them.
The ones we actually have detected are from transients, and thus will make up a very small part of the total GW energy density, or to the "graviton number density".

What really makes up the bulk will be the "floor", the background of gravitational waves.
Its spectrum is not well-known at all.
We have upper bounds on its total energy density, on the order of $\Omega_{gw} < 10^{-10}$, where $\Omega_{gw}$ is, roughly speaking, the "fraction of the total energy density in the universe consisting of gravitational waves", and the corresponding spectrum is $\Omega_{gw}(f)$.

However, that is not enough to compute an upper bound on the number of gravitons: the energy density is given by (see equation 2.20 in [1](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s41114-017-0004-1)),
$$ \Omega_{gw} = \int \mathrm{d}\log f\ \Omega_{gw} (f)
$$
while the total number of gravitons will be given by an integral in the form
$$ n_{gw} = \int \mathrm{d}\log f\ \Omega_{gw} (f) \frac{\rho_c}{hf}\,.
$$

So, we need an explicit expression for $\Omega_{gw}(f)$ to compute this integral!
Someone bolder than me may actually go through in doing the computation for some spectrum models which are currently compatible with data,
I'll just give a heuristic consideration: the corresponding $\Omega$ for photons is about $5 \times 10^{-5}$, so about 5 orders of magnitude higher than the one from gravitons.
However, gravitons are typically very low-frequency!

If we take an inflationary-like spectrum, the bulk of the distribution today will lie below $10^{-16} \text{Hz}$ (see figure 84 in [1](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s41114-017-0004-1)).
This is more than 25 orders of magnitude lower than the frequency of CMB photons!

So, the same energy density for gravitons and photons would be made up of at least $10^{25}$ more gravitons than photons, since each of them will be so much less energetic.

This all considered, I'd say that probably the number density of gravitons is at least 20 orders of magnitude higher than that of photons, leading to $N \gtrsim 10^{110}$.
Of course, this is *extremely* rough, and under the assumption that gravitons with a wavelength of several Megaparsecs can be treated quantum-mechanically, which is a shaky hypothesis, to say the least.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this fascinating answer.

Comment: Could this huge number of gravitons be the origin of the cosmological constant?

Comment: @Christian Nope! They behave in the wrong way (like radiation) and despite the (potentially) very large number their energy density is tiny